URLDownloadToFile() reference undefined (c++)
DISCLAIMER: Yes, I do know that there is one that has the exact same program as me. link to that post: Error When trying the urldownloadtofile function. I coincidentally have the exact same issue.
The suggestion is to change the following to link -lurlmon.lib option as #pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib") but that works only for MSVC. I am using MinGW gcc compiler.
I have typed the following into the terminal to build, but nothing happens

My code is simply:
if (S_OK == URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, link, destination, 0, NULL)){
    cout << "Successed in downloading file no. " << count << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Failed in downloading file no. " << count << endl;
}

where link and destination are const char* variables, and count is just the file count (yes, the entire thing is in a for loop).

As the linked anwer says, you need to pass -lurlmon as a command line option to your compiler.

#pragma comment only works on MSVC.

I've closed this because it seems that the answer to your question is the same as the dupe. If this is not the case than can you explain how the dupe does not work for you. It seems to me you just got confused between -lurlmon.lib and -lurlmon

answering john: I opened this because I didn't know how to implement -lurlmon to my code. Is it alright for you to show me how?

You add -lurlmon to whatever command you use for compiling your code. Show that instead.

Use @username when replying to send us notifications.

That looks like a successful compilation to me.

@HolyBlackCat but no executable files are made

Can you show the list of files in that directory after compilation?

@HolyBlackCat forgive me, a mistake has been made, it is alright now
